# Preventing from form submission when validation fails

Tags: javascript, jsp

How do I prevent this from submission when validation fails? I don't know what to put in the `validateForm` function... I have this form:

```
<form action="ChangePassword" method="POST">  
    <input type="submit" value="Change Password" onclick="validateForm();"/>
</form>
```

And the `validateform` function:

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        if(document.getElementById("passError").innerHTML !== "") {
            alert("There are some errors.");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return from your event handler function.

You are currently only returning from `validateForm` which is a function you call *from* your event handler function.

```
onclick="return validateForm();"
```

Good practise would be:

- to perform the check when it is submitted rather then only when the submit button is clicked (i.e. use `onsubmit` on the form instead of `onclick` on the button).
- to [bind your event handlers with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead of depending on globals and intrinsic event attributes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to stop the bubbling from your scope with e.preventDefault() instead of return false ?

```
    function validateForm(event) {
    if(document.getElementById("passError").innerHTML !== "") {
        alert("There are some errors.");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to do it in your form. Not in submit button. Like:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

And also return `true` if your validation passes in your validate function.